# How to Pass Image or path from Recyclerview to next Activity onClick so that i can display Image Full View?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I really don't know how to do this. I have tried some tutorial but not worked for me ... i've already done the this with many Methods but unable to do this.

Here is my RecyclerView Holder

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
String s;
Bitmap image;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
}

@Override    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent imageIntent  = new Intent(view.getContext(),GalleryFullImage.class);
    imageIntent.putExtra("id",getAdapterPosition());
    view.getContext().startActivity(imageIntent);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Here is my Recyclerview Adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemList) {
    this.arrayList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrayList.get(position));
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

@Override    public int getItemCount() {
    return this.arrayList.size();
}}
```

Here is my GalleryActivity

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> stringList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_gallery);
    setTitle("Gallery");

    stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Be sure that this file is exist !!

    String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Country";
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    try
    {
        Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator()
        {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        });
        for (File file : files) {
        stringList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Sort Error", e.getMessage());
    }

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), stringList);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);


}
```

}

Comment: Are you images in drawables folder or you are loading from internet?

Comment: I am Using Images from a folder Stored on Device

Comment: I dont know about device images, but i can give solution on how to pass image to next activity with full screen if the images are in drawables folder, hopefully you can make changes then

Comment: does you RecyclerViewHolders.class resides inside RecyclerViewAdapter.class ??? forget the Image show on next page, does you listen click event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading the bitmap from file in `onBindViewHolder`, you can just pass the path instead in `onClick` and decode it again in your next activity. This may require a bit of work in your case since your `ViewHolder` is defined separately from your RecyclerView so it does not have access to your dataset. For starters, move your `ViewHolder` so it can be a static nested class of your `RecyclerView`. Something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolders>
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ....

    public static class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    ....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(...);
        intent.putExtra("path",arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        /* send intent*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am Getting Position of Image by using my method. How can i use that position in FullimageActivity for displaying Full screen Image?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to apply onClickListener in you viewholder, take the clicked adapter position in integer and pass it in next your fullscreen activity

Here is the full code, hope it helps

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private final Integer image_ids[] = {
      R.drawable.image1,
      R.drawable.image2,
      R.drawable.image3,
      R.drawable.image4,
      R.drawable.image5,

};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),gridColumnlayout);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createLists);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
 private ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData(){

    ArrayList<CreateList> theimage = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
        CreateList createList = new CreateList();
        createList.setImage_ID(image_ids[i]);
        theimage.add(createList);
    }
    return theimage;
}

}
```

**CreateList Class**

```
public class CreateList {

 private Integer image_id;

 public Integer getImage_ID() {
    return image_id;
 }

 public void setImage_ID(Integer android_image_url) {
    this.image_id = android_image_url;
 }

}
```

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
private Context context;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "FullScreen Image";


public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    CreateList currentList = galleryList.get(i);
    Glide.with(context).load(currentList.getImage_ID()).centerCrop().crossFade().into(viewHolder.img);

    viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            String stringID = Integer.valueOf(pos).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyAdapter.this.context, FullScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, stringID);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
```

}

**FullScreen Activity**

```
public class FullScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


 private final Integer image_ids[] = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
 };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyAdapter.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int position = Integer.parseInt(message);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_ids[position]);

    } 
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```